# MultipleHiddenInput renders only if with initial data

Tags: python, django, forms

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_hidden_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput, choices=(...))


def my_view(request):
  form = MyForm(initial={'my_hidden_field': MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)})
```

With such code, if remove `initial` argument from call to `MyForm`, `my_hidden_field` will not be rendered in HTML, but if remove `MultipleHiddenInput` widget then, it will appear again.
How to make it being rendered properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way it is implemented. If you do not pass any values, then there is nothing to render, because it is hidden anyway, so user just cant alter the values.

You can see the implementation here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L316

If you need to render it, you will need to pass some initial data to it, but it is strange, what is the use case exactly ?

Comment: Values of multi-choice input is `choices`, which is provided to widget - that how I was treated `MultipleHiddenInput`. In my case - I want to capture values from checkbox from other form to hidden checkbox via JavaScript.

Comment: In case of MultipleHiddenInput its not, please see the implementation - they are iterating over values, not choices in order to render each item. You can create checkboxes dynamically via JavaScript.